# How can I cut the names from the output of "uniq -c"?

Tags: bash

Given a file with some lines, I printed the content of this file (by `uniq -c file`) and I want to sort this file and after it, I want to take only the lines (without the numbers from `uniq -c`) , how can I do it?

I tried to do `cat ${file} | uniq -c | sort -nr | cut -d" " -f2` , and I get empty output.

How can I fix it?

Exists way to remove all the spaces in the beginning of the lines that I get from `uniq -c`?

---

For example:

given the following input:

> a
>   b
>   c
>   a
>   a
>   g
>   d
>   d

I get the following output from `cat file | sort | uniq -c` :

```
  3 a
  1 b
  1 c
  2 d
  1 g
```

(In the beginning I get spaces)